# Три кнопки в одной форме

Tags: javascript, html

На сайте есть форма, один `<input>` и три кнопки(`<button>`) в зависимости от желаемого действия. Как можно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на любую из них было действие `submit` и еще передавалось, какая из трех кнопок была нажата? Допустим у кнопок есть идентификаторы `1,2,3` и в *PHP* скрипте я бы по этой цифре мог бы понять, какое действие выбрали.

```html
<form action="check.php" method="post">
  <input class="input" type="text" size="15" onkeyup="return proverka(this);" onchange="return proverka(this);" />
  <button class="button left" type="submit">1</button>
  <button class="button center" type="submit">2</button>
  <button class="button right" type="submit">3</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте атрибуты `name` и `value`.

```
<button class="button left" name="whattodo" value="1" type="submit">1</button>
<button class="button center" name="whattodo" value="2" type="submit">2</button>
<button class="button right" name="whattodo" value="3" type="submit">3</button>
```